# How to remove part of the array?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

The program I am working on involves reading and determining the difference between i - (i+1) and i-(i-1) from excel.

If the difference exceeds 4 then the program deletes the row at i.

The program works well at the first try. Suddenly, it says that "You can not change part of an Array".

```
Option Explicit

Sub Data_Delet()

    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, i As Double
    Dim rkill As Range
    ' a,b, and c are used as steps in order to proceed to the next data points
    a = 18
    b = 0
    c = 0

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        ' The second do loop delete data points that does not follow the requirements
        Do
        If Abs(.Cells(a - 1, 2) - .Cells(a, 2)) > 4 And Abs(.Cells(a, 2) - .Cells(a + 1, 2)) > 4 Then
             If rkill Is Nothing Then
                Set rkill = Rows(a)
             Else
                Set rkill = Union(rkill, Rows(a))
             End If
        End If
        a = a + 1
        Loop Until .Cells(a, 2).Value = ""
        If Not rkill Is Nothing Then rkill.EntireRow.Delete
     ' The third Do loop determines the number of data points that are still present after deleting the data points
      Do
        i = .Cells(17 + c, 1)
        c = c + 1
    Loop Until .Cells(17 + c, 1).Value = ""

  ' The if statment determine whether or not the number data points from before are the same after deletion process
     If b = c Then
     .Cells(2, 5) = "N"
     Else
     .Cells(2, 5) = "Y"
     End If

      ' c is the number of data point after deletion
     .Cells(12, 5) = c

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error *"You cannot change part of an array"* on `rkill.EntireRow.Delete` means that the row you want to delete is intersecting a range referenced in an array formula (a formula with braces).

Excel does not allow this. One way would be to remove the offending array formula(s) at the start of your code, and redefine it/them again at the end of your code. Or find a solution to turn these array formulas into normal formulas.